# Filter activerecord by nested ID and value combination in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, filtering

Lets say I have two models with a many to many relationship: **Item** and **Property**

Now I have an array of properties and I want to filter all items which properties match a given value (lets say a boolean value: property.value = true)

When I try

```
@items = Item.includes(:properties).where(:properties => {:id => [1,2,3].to_a, :value => true})
```

I would like to get all items where property(1) is true **AND** property(2) is true and so on. But with the code above I get all items related to the property id's and where **any** property is true. How should I change my code?

I would appreciate not to use a gem for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are almost there:

```
property_ids = [1,2,3]
Item.joins(:properties).
     where(:properties => { :id => property_ids, :value => true }).
     group('items.id').
     having('COUNT(properties.id) >= ?', property_ids.size)
```

`joins` does an `INNER JOIN` and is preferred over `includes` when you really need to join tables.

`where` is basically the conditions you already had, the only change is that there is not need to call `to_a` on the array.

Than you have to `group` to make that `COUNT` in SQL work.

`having` extracts the lines that have at least the expected number of property lines matching the condition.

Comment: thanks! But somehow this has no filter effect at all. No matter how many propertiy id's are inside property_ids, the result always shows all items...

Comment: Even Items which do not have `properties.size`  number of `true` values?

Comment: Yes, even those. But to be honest, I have not fully understood the group and having part yet. In my app, every item has relations to all available properties and their value can be true or false. I have some items where all properties.values are false. But even those are not filtered out.

Comment: Can you please run the above code in your Rails console and add `.to_sql` to the query. That will show you the SQL that is generated. Please post the generated SQL.

Comment: In my case courses = items and labels = properties. Here is the .to_sql result:  `"SELECT \"courses\".* FROM \"courses\" INNER JOIN \"courseandlabels\" ON \"courseandlabels\".\"course_id\" = \"courses\".\"id\" INNER JOIN \"labels\" ON \"labels\".\"id\" = \"courseandlabels\".\"label_id\" WHERE \"labels\".\"id\" IN (1, 2, 3) AND \"labels\".\"active\" = 't' GROUP BY courses.id HAVING COUNT(labels.id) >= 3"`

Comment: Of course it was my mistake. Now I have understood why you are counting: To ensure all requested properties are true... Very cool, thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad I was able to help.